# Detect if App is linked to CoreLocation framework

Tags: ios, core-location

What is the CoreLocation equivalent of _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H or _COREDATADEFINES_H?

Can I use the below to detect if the app links to the CoreLocation framework?

```
#ifdef __CORELOCATION__
// do something
#endif
```

I've seen popular open-source frameworks like RestKit and AFNetworking(?) use this technique.

Comment: You can use that to get the same result as AFNetworking, but as far as I know that will only tell you if the header was included.  It will not determine the link status of the framework.

Comment: @borrrden this is right I think, which is why AFNetworking gives errors if you have linked frameworks but not included them in the pch. A test for linking might be to create a class contained in the framework and see if it is nil, e.g. `if (NSClassFromString(@"CLLocationManager"))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use `#ifdef __CORELOCATION__`. If you check the `CoreLocation.h` here you will see that if defines:

```
#ifndef __CORELOCATION__
#define __CORELOCATION__
```

But why did you not just test to theory?

Comment: I tried but I was getting unexpected results. Perhaps, I have some issues elsewhere.